# ulong[] to uint[] - is this good practice?

Tags: c#

I stumpled upon this problem and saw this solution:

```
ulong[] ulongArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
uint[]  uintArray  = null;

uintArray  = (uint[]) (object) ulongArray;
ulongArray = (ulong[])(object) uintArray;
```

and I am wondering if that is how you do it? Looks a little strange to me ..

Comment: This is like using `void*` in old C-days. It is good if you are exactly aware what are you doing. It is bad otherwise.

Comment: Copy-paste it into the Main() method of a new console mode app and watch it shrivel up, emit a puff of smoke and die.

Comment: Array covariance is broken in C#. Read Eric Lippert's [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While that will compile, it will throw an exception at execution time. The two types just aren't compatible.

A *similar* situation would be:

```
uint[] uintArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] intArray = (int[]) (object) uintArray;
```

That *will* work - the CLR is happy to treat a `uint[]` reference as an `int[]` reference, even though C# isn't. (The same is true for conversions between arrays of enum types and their underlying integral types.)

I'd be wary of using it, just in terms of surprising anyone reading the code - but in certain cases it *could* be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ulong[] ulongArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
uint[] uintArray = ulongArray.Select(u => (uint) u).ToArray();
```